# google places location not working

Tags: android, api, location

good morning, I wanted to ask if anyone has been the same problem that me.
I'm making an app of google maps and one day suddenly no longer collects my location, I tested with earlier versions in this worked fine, if I had changed something and they not give me my location, I also tested on other devices and nothing, it has stopped of work from one day to another. I wanted to know if it is due to something about google account Developer Console or if the api key may expire or something

thank you.

EDIT:

```
public class BuscarActivity extends ListActivity {

private GoogleMap mMapa;    
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location location;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.buscar_activity);       
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    mMapa = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapaBuscar))
            .getMap();          

    mMapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    locationManager = new LocationManager(this);

    getLocalizacion();

    mMapa.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
        //con el objeto position puedo recuperar todos los datos necesarios
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {               
            getLocation();   
        }
    });
}       


private void getLocalizacion() {            
    //I'm used this firstly
    //location = mMapa.getMyLocation(); 
    //but now I'm using this although anyone works now
    location = locationManager.getLocation();                               
}


public class LocationManager implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {   
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient; 
public static Location mLastLocation;
private Context context;

public LocationManager(Context c) {     
    this.context = c;
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    onStart();
}


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}       


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);    
}


public Location getLocation(){      
    return mLastLocation;
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i("conection fail", "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
            + result.getErrorCode());
}

public void onDisconnected() {
    Log.i("disconnected", "Disconnected");
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i("connection fail", "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


public void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


public void onStop() {      
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the key expires, try posting your code you might have missed something out

Comment: try using `location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);`
in your `getLocalizacion()`.

I hope this helps

Comment: nothing. I have done a locationManager.getProviders(false) and It returned only 2, 1 called passive and another gps and in my app I need to find the location via network or wifi and I think the mobile could be broken but I tried another phone and is the same